# How to customize mailNotificationAudioFiles[@"BusyTone"] with own audio file?

Tags: ios, objective-c, char, constants, nsdata

Is there a way to assign `NSData` to `const char`. i know `NSString` can be assigned to `const char` using

```
 const char *value = [myString UTF8String];
```

i tried to assign `NSData` using

```
const char *value = [myData bytes];
```

and also

```
 NSString *dataString = [NSString alloc]initWithData:myData encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
 const char *value = [dataString UTF8String];
```

but did not work. myData is a `NSData` containing audio data in it.

Edit :

existing one

```
resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Busytone" ofType:@"wav"];
linphone_core_set_tone([LinphoneManager getLc], LinphoneToneBusy , [resourcePath UTF8String]);
```

i am trying to replace that with

```
NSData*data= configure.mailNotificationAudioFiles[@"BusyTone"];
NSString *str =[[NSString alloc]initWithData:data encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
linphone_core_set_tone([LinphoneManager getLc], LinphoneToneBusy ,[str UTF8String]);
```

the method to which data is passed

```
LINPHONE_PUBLIC void linphone_core_set_tone(LinphoneCore *lc, LinphoneToneID id, const char *audiofile);
```

Comment: If it's audio data then it's not `const char`, it's `const uint8_t`.  What are you passing this `const char *` data to?

Comment: `const char *value= [myData bytes];` should work. what's the problem?

Comment: @trojanfoe i am passing this to a method which has a const car parameter to play audio. however if audio is loaded from NSBundle and assign that path as nsstring with UTF8String it works.

Comment: Show that code; it's important to know.

Comment: @Cy-4AH bytes is a const var . Using this wont show error but audio wont be played.

Comment: OK and what is in `configure.mailNotificationAudioFiles`?  What does it contain?  What was it populated from?

Comment: nsdictionary with audiofile as value and Busytone is key

Comment: You need know what `linphone_core_set_tone` waits in `audiofile` argument. I think it tone name or file path. So instead raw bytes, you should provide file path.

Answer (score 0):

OK, taking a punt at this answer; the OP wants to replace the use of the hardcoded `@"BusyTone"` filename with something that is, I guess, configurable.

Assuming all the sound files are contained in the app bundle, then this should do the job:

```
NSString *soundFile = configure.mailNotificationAudioFiles[@"BusyTone"];
if (!soundFile)
    soundFile = @"BusyTone";
NSString *resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:soundFile
                                                         ofType:@"wav"];
if (resourcePath) {
    linphone_core_set_tone([LinphoneManager getLc], LinphoneToneBusy , [resourcePath UTF8String]);
} else {
    // Handle error
}
```

Comment: code throws esception in NSBundle line -[_NSInlineData characterAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5716000

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys, i solved the issue by doing this

```
 if(!configure.mailNotificationAudioFiles[@"BusyTone"])
            {
                resourcePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Busytone" ofType:@"wav"];
                linphone_core_set_tone([LinphoneManager getLc], LinphoneToneBusy , [resourcePath UTF8String]);

            }
            else{

                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *filePath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Busytone.wav"];
                NSData * data =configure.mailNotificationAudioFiles[@"BusyTone"];
                NSError *writeError = nil;
                [data writeToFile:filePath options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:&writeError];
                if (writeError) {
                    NSLog(@"Error writing file: %@", writeError);
                }
                linphone_core_set_tone([LinphoneManager getLc], LinphoneToneBusy ,[filePath UTF8String]);

            }
```